# Problem with composite relations

Tags: functions, relations

The composition $\mathcal{R_2}\circ \mathcal{R_1}$ of the relations $\mathcal{R_1}$ and $\mathcal{R_2}$ is defined as follows:

$\mathcal{R_2}\circ \mathcal{R_1}:=\{(x,z)\ |\exists\ y(x\mathcal{R_1}y\land y\mathcal{R_2}z)\}$.

In particular if $\mathcal{R_1}\subset X\times Y $ and $\mathcal{R_2}\subset Y\times Z$, then $\mathcal{R}=\mathcal{R_2}\circ \mathcal{R_1}\subset X\times Z$, and

$x\mathcal{Rz}:=\exists\  y\ ((y\in Y)\land(x\mathcal{R_1y)\land(y\mathcal{R_2z}))}$.

Let $\Delta_X$ be the diagonal of $X^2$ and $\Delta_Y$ be the diagonal of $Y^2$. Show that if the relations $\mathcal{R_1}\subset X\times Y$ and $\mathcal{R_2}\subset Y\times X$ are such that $(\mathcal{R_2}\circ \mathcal{R_1}=\Delta_X)\land(\mathcal{R_1}\circ \mathcal{R_2}=\Delta_Y)$, then both relations are functional and define mutually inverse mappings of $X$ and $Y$.

My working thus far:

$(x,x)\in \Delta_X\Rightarrow (x,x)\in \mathcal{R_2}\circ \mathcal{R_1}\Rightarrow \mathcal{R_2}\circ \mathcal{R_1}\subset X^2$.

Similarly,

$(y,y)\in \Delta_Y\Rightarrow (y,y)\in \mathcal{R_1}\circ \mathcal{R_2}\Rightarrow \mathcal{R_1}\circ \mathcal{R_2}\subset Y^2$.

This is the furthest I got. I am not sure if I have any errors in my working and how to show that the relations are functional.

Comment: What does it mean for a relation to be functional?

Comment: If for every element in the domain of definition there exists a unique element in the range of values such that the relation holds. Struggling to see which bit of the definition in the question to use so I can verify this.

Comment: @shredalert: right you are.  Another way to phrase this is: a relation $R\subset X\times Y$ is functional iff $\forall x \in X$ and $y_1, y_2 \in Y$, $xRy_1 \wedge xR y_2 \implies y_1 = y_2$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to whether the question asks to prove that the composite relations are functional or that the individual relations are functional. I think I see how to prove that the composite relations are functional. I'm lost as to how to prove $\mathcal{R_1}$ and $\mathcal{R_2}$ are functional.

Comment: Using the question: $x\mathcal{R}x:=\exists y((y\in Y)\land (x\mathcal{R_1}y)\land (y\mathcal{R_2}x))$. Does this show that one of the relations is functional? If so, which?

Comment: I think I got the wrong one. Maybe $\mathcal{R_2}\circ \mathcal{R_1}:= \{(x,y)|\exists y(x\mathcal{R_1}y\land y\mathcal{R_2}x)\Rightarrow x=y$ because the composite relation is equivalent to $\Delta_X$ But I still don't understand where I use this to show that the individual relations are functional.

Answer (score 1):

Let's show that $xR_1y \iff yR_2x$ or in other words, $R_1$ as a subset of $X \times Y$ is just the interchange of the two components of $R_2$ as a subset of $Y \times X$. (You could call $R_1$ and $R_2$ inverse and say $R_1 = R_2^{-1}$ and vice versa).

Note that since $R_1 \circ R_2 = \Delta_Y$, we have that the domain of $R_2$, $\operatorname{dom}(R_2) = Y$ and similary, $R_2 \circ R_1 = \Delta_X$ implies that  $\operatorname{dom}(R_1)=X$.

Let $(x,y)\in R_1$. Then $y \in \operatorname{dom}(R_2)$ and hence, for some $z\in X$, $yR_2z$. Thus, $(x,z)\in R_1 \circ R_2$ and $(x,z) \in \Delta_X$, which implies $z=x$, i.e. $(y,x)\in R_2$ and furthermore, $x$ is the only element of $x$ which fulfils this, which implies that $R_2$ is a function and has a trivial multivalued part.

Similarly, we get from $(y,x)\in R_2$ that $(x,y)\in R_1$ and $R_1$ is a function.

Now, since $\operatorname{dom}(R_1)=\operatorname{ran}(R_2)=X$ and $\operatorname{dom}(R_2)=\operatorname{ran}(R_1)=Y$ we have that both relations are surjective.

Furthermore, the argument above shows that $xR_1y$ and $zR_1y$ implies $x=z$, i.e. $R_1$ is injective. Analogously for $R_2$.

Thus, $R_1$ and $R_2$ are biijective functions and their respective inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be established.

1) $\mathcal{R_1}$ and $\mathcal{R_2}$ are functional relationships. This can be done by showing that for every first element in the set of ordered pairs, there is a unique second element.

2) $\mathcal{R_1}$ and $\mathcal{R_2}$ define mutually inverse mappings of $X$ and $Y$. This can be done by showing that both composite relations are identity mappings. This will lead to proving that they are bijective, and hence, mutually inverse.

1) $x_1 \in X \Rightarrow x_1 \Delta_X x_1 \Rightarrow x_1 {\mathcal{R_1} \circ {}\mathcal{R_2} x_1}$.

A/Q, $\mathcal{R_1} \circ \mathcal{R_2}:= \{(x_1,y_1)|\exists y_1(x_1\mathcal{R_1}y_1 \land y_1\mathcal{R_2}x_1)\}$.

This means that there exists at least one unique $y_1$ such that $x_1\mathcal{R_1}y_1 \land y_1\mathcal{R_2}x_1$.

Need to show that $y$s are unique for every $x$. Try to prove by contradiction.

Suppose $\exists x_1\mathcal{R_1}y_2$.

This means

$x_1\mathcal{R_1}y_1 \land x_1\mathcal{R_1}y_2$ [There are two $y$s for some $x$] $\Rightarrow y_1\mathcal{R_2}x_1 \land x_1\mathcal{R_1}y_2 \Rightarrow y_1\mathcal{R_1}\circ \mathcal{R_2}y_2 \Rightarrow y_1\Delta_Y y_2\Rightarrow y_1=y_2$.

This means that for each ordered pair the second elemt for each first element in $\mathcal{R_1}$ is unique. This proves that $\mathcal{R_1}$ is a functional relation.

An analogous argument can be used to prove that $\mathcal{R_2}$ is a functional relation.

2) $x\mathcal{R_1}y$ and $y\mathcal{R_2}x$ are functions.

$x\mathcal{R_1}y:=f_1:X\to Y$.

$y\mathcal{R_2}x:=f_2:Y\to X$.

A/Q, $f_2\circ f_1=e_X$ and $f_1\circ f_2=e_Y$ where $e_X$ and $e_Y$ are identity mappings. i.e., they map the domain to itself.

$X=e_X(X)=(f_2\circ f_1)(X)=f_2(f_1(X))\subset f_2(Y)$.

Therefore, $f_2$ is surjective.

Further, if $x_1\in X$ and $x_2\in X$ then

$x_1\neq x_2\Rightarrow e_X(x_1)\neq e_X(x_2)\Rightarrow (f_2\circ f_1)(x_1)\neq (f_2\circ f_1)(x_2)\Rightarrow f_2(f_1(x_1))\neq f_2(f_1(x_2))\Rightarrow f_1(x_1)\neq f_1(x_2)$

Therefore, $f_1$ is injective.

An analogous argument can be used to show that in the case of $f_1\circ f_1=e_Y$, $f_1$ is surjective and $f_2$ is injective.

This implies that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are mutually inverse mappings.

Comment: How do we know that $x_1 R_1 y_2 \Rightarrow y_2 R_2 x_1$?You could show, as an item 0) that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are inverese relations, i.e. $x R_1 y \iff y R_2 x$, using the fact that their compositions are diagonals. You don't need the functions for this yet.

Comment: That comes from the definition in the question. The book I'm studying out of (Zorich's mathematical analysis volume I) doesn't work with inverse relations, so using it didn't occur to me.

Comment: It doesn't come from the definition of the concatenation. Just because $xR_1y_1$ and $y_1R_2x$, this doesn't imply that for some $y_2$ witrh $xR_1 y_2 $ that alse $xR_2 y_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting to see that this can be also answered in a different way, in which we avoid mentioning elements as far as possible and argue more algebraically.

We are given $\mathcal{R}_1 \subseteq X \times Y$ and that
$\mathcal{R}_2 \subseteq Y \times X$. We are also given that $\mathcal{R}_2 \circ \mathcal{R}_1 = \Delta_X$ and $\mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_2 = \Delta_Y$. From these we have to show that $\mathcal{R}_1$ and $\mathcal{R}_2$ are functional and inverse to each other.

Note that $\mathcal{R}_1$ being functional is equivalent to
$$\mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_1^{-1} \subseteq \Delta_Y.$$
Informally: imagine tracing backwards along $\mathcal{R}_1$ from an element $y \in Y$ to some $x \in X$ and then forwards from $x$ to any $y' \in Y$. Being functional means that whenever we do this we have to have $y = y'$, that is, $(y,y') \in \Delta_Y$.

Similarly, $\mathcal{R}_2$ being functional is equivalent to
$$\mathcal{R}_2 \circ \mathcal{R}_2^{-1} \subseteq \Delta_X.$$
We also need to know that the diagonal is the identity relation for composition,
so that
$$\Delta_Y \circ \mathcal{R}_1 \circ \Delta_X = \mathcal{R}_1, \text{ and } \Delta_X \circ \mathcal{R}_2 \circ \Delta_Y = \mathcal{R}_2.$$
We do need this property which holds for an arbitrary relation $\mathcal{R}$:
$$\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{R} \circ \mathcal{R}^{-1} \circ \mathcal{R}.$$
Now, everything falls out very neatly:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal{R}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_1^{-1} \circ \mathcal{R}_1 
& \Rightarrow & 
\mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_2 \subseteq 
\mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_1^{-1} \circ \mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_2\\
& \Rightarrow & 
\Delta_Y \subseteq 
\mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_1^{-1} \circ \Delta_Y \\
& \Rightarrow & 
\mathcal{R}_2 \circ \Delta_Y \subseteq \mathcal{R}_2 \circ
\mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_1^{-1} \\
& \Rightarrow & 
\mathcal{R}_2 \subseteq \Delta_X \circ \mathcal{R}_1^{-1} \\
& \Rightarrow & \mathcal{R}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{R}_1^{-1}
\end{array}$$
For exactly the same reason $\mathcal{R}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{R}_2^{-1}$, so taking inverses of the relations, $\mathcal{R}_1^{-1} \subseteq \mathcal{R}_2$ and hence (using the fact that $\mathcal{R}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{R}_1^{-1}$) we get $\mathcal{R}_2 = \mathcal{R}_1^{-1}$ and $\mathcal{R}_1 = \mathcal{R}_2^{-1}$.

The property of being functional can be justified explicitly by noting:
$$\mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_1^{-1} = \mathcal{R}_1 \circ \mathcal{R}_2 = \Delta_Y,
\text{ and } \mathcal{R}_2 \circ \mathcal{R}_2^{-1} = \mathcal{R}_2 \circ \mathcal{R}_1 = \Delta_X.$$